# PickerView within UiActivityView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'd like to use the `UIActivityView` for letting the user choose a filter for my `UITableView`. Therefore I need a `UIPickerView` within my `UIActivityView`.

Is this possible using Swift?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `UIPickerView` as `subview` to your `UIActivityViewcontroller`:

```
activityView.view.addSubview(pickerView)
```